# Iterate vector inside method

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I am currently learning C++ , and I have following working code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        map<unsigned int, list<mpz_class>> otp;

        // .....

        for(auto it1 = otp.begin(); it1 != otp.end(); ++it1) {
                bool first = true;
                for(auto it2 = it1->second.begin(); it2 != it1->second.end(); ++it2) {
                        if (!first) {
                                cout << ", ";
                        } else {
                                first = false;
                        }
                        cout << *it2;
                }
        }
}
```

I wanted to put the printing of the list into an function.

This was my try:

```
void prnt_list(vector it, ostream outstr, string delimiter) {
        bool first = true;
        for(auto it2 = it.begin(); it2 != it.end(); ++it2) {
                if (!first) {
                        outstr << delimiter;
                } else {
                        first = false;
                }
                outstr << *it2;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    map<unsigned int, list<mpz_class>> otp;

    // .....

    for(auto it1 = otp.begin(); it1 != otp.end(); ++it1) {
        prnt_list(it1->second, cout, ", ");
    }
)
```

It does not compile:

```
error: variable or field 'prnt_list' declared void
error: missing template arguments before 'it'
error: expected primary-expression before 'outstr'
error: expected primary-expression before 'delimiter'
```

Then I tried this:

```
template <typename T>
void prnt_list<T>(vector<T> it, ostream outstr, string delimiter) {
    ...
}
```

But it also doesn't work.

Also, I also don't like the enforced template, because I want to allow any vector. It would be much more comfortable, if I could use the `auto` keyword somehow.

Comment: Try `ostream&` instead of `ostream`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `std::vector` probably.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `std::vector` . I thought this is what I need to get `.begin` and `.end()`

Comment: @milleniumbug  Is there implicit conversion from std::list<int> to std::vector<int> in C++?

Comment: std::copy(otp.begin(), otp.end(), [infix_ostream_iterator](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489)<mpz_class>(std::cout, ", "));

Comment: @JerryCoffin  Did it make it to boost? I found a related proposal, not sure what's the link between yours and [this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4066.htm).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Where is `infix_ostream_iterator` declared ? I am using G++ (I never used Boost library)

Comment: @vsoftco: no--I thought about submitting it to Boost, but then found the same one you linked above, and didn't see much point in submitting another.

Comment: @rinntech: the link goes to the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending a `list` to a function that expects a `vector`
the generic could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
void prnt_list(const T& it, std::ostream& outstr, const std::string& delimiter)
{
    bool first = true;
    for( auto&& obj : it ) {
        if (!first)
            outstr << delimiter;
        else
            first = false;
        outstr << obj;
    }
}
```

also note that `<<` has to be defined for `mpz_class`

it requires the headers `<string>` and `<iostream>`

Answer (score 3):

The function can be defined the following way

```
std::ostream & prnt_list( const std::list<mpz_class> &lst, 
                          std::ostream &os = std::cout, 
                          const char *delimiter = ", " ) 
{
    bool first = true;

    for ( const auto &obj : lst ) 
    {
        if ( first ) first = false;
        else os << delimiter;

        os << obj;
    }

    return os;
}
```

and called like

```
for ( const auto &p : otp ) prnt_list( p.second ) << std::endl;
```

You could write a general function for any container. For example

```
template <class Container>
std::ostream & prnt_list( const Container &container, 
                          std::ostream &os = std::cout, 
                          const char *delimiter = ", " ) 
{
    bool first = true;

    for ( const auto &obj : container ) 
    {
        if ( first ) first = false;
        else os << delimiter;

        os << obj;
    }

    return os;
}
```

As for your code then at least identifier vector is not declared and streams are not copyable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. `const auto &p` seems to be a very elegant and easy way to iterate. At the method, I would add `template<typename T>` to make it a bit more universal.
May I ask a second question? Is something like this possible `std::cerr << prnt_list(x) << std::endl` ? (Maybe even without the `ostream` argument, because the function "knows" where its output will be (which is `stderr` in this example)?

Comment: @rinntech  You can call the function like prnt_list( x, std::cerr ) << std::endl;

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just curious if it is possible to implement it without this argument. I am curious about many things when I learn a programming language.  The problem I had was this: `std::cout << "x = {" << prnt_list(x) << "}" << std::endl` . This doesn't work, so I have to split it up: `std::cout << "x = {"; prnt_list(x) << "}" << std::endl`

Comment: @rinntech  To split the statement is not a bad solution.

Comment: why const char* for delimiter?

Comment: @sp2danny Keep It Simpler Stupid. (KISS)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is :

```
map<unsigned int, list<mpz_class>> otp;
```

has as second a list, and as a first argument to prnt_list you have vector. Why?

To fix those errors use following signature for prnt_list:

```
template<typename T>
void prnt_list(list<T>& it, ostream& outstr, string delimiter) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I wonder, would this function need to be implemented for each class which has `begin()` and `end()` ? I am new in C++, and I thought that vector, map, list etc. were some kind of descendant of a generic iterator type which provides begin and end. So, there is no generalized form of this?

Comment: to make it more general, you don't mention the container type, so instead of saying `list<T>&` you just say `T&`. the various containers don't have an inheritance relationship, but the interfaces is similar enough that you can use them generically with templates

Comment: @rinntech exactly as in sp2danny comment, if you use begin(it) instead of it.begin() (and the same for end), it will also work for arrays and other containers with no begin/end methods but for which globally overloaded function begin/end exists. I am not sure but if you use auto then it is implemented this way.

Answer (score 1):

expandind on Vlad's answer - allowing print_list to participate in an `ostream` `<<` chain:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

namespace detail {

    // it's called a simple list printer because it assumes that
    // list::value_type is printable
    template<class T, class A>
    struct simple_list_printer {
        simple_list_printer(const std::list<T, A>& list, std::string delimiter)
        : _list { list }
        , _delimiter { delimiter }
        {}

        void write(std::ostream& os) const {
            bool first = true;

            for ( const auto &obj : _list )
            {
                if ( first ) first = false;
                else os << _delimiter;

                os << obj;
            }
        }
    private:
        const std::list<T, A>& _list;
        std::string _delimiter;
    };

    // stream an simple_list_printer to any ostream
    template<class T, class A>
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const simple_list_printer<T, A>& slp)
    {
        slp.write(os);
        return os;
    }
}

// a mockup of mpz_class
struct mpz_class {

    void write(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "{ i am an mpz - write my members here }";
    }
};

// stream an mpz to any ostream
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const mpz_class& mpz)
{
    mpz.write(os);
    return os;
}

// construct a simple_list_printer
template<class A>
detail::simple_list_printer<mpz_class, A>
print_list(const std::list<mpz_class, A>& list, std::string delimiter = std::string { ", " })
{
    return { list, std::move(delimiter) };
}

int main()
{
    std::list<mpz_class> a { {}, {} };

    std::cout << print_list(a) << std::endl;
    std::cerr << print_list(a) << std::endl;
    std::clog << print_list(a) << std::endl;

    std::cout << print_list(a, "\n") << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cerr << print_list(a, " * ") << std::endl;
    std::clog << print_list(a, " <--> ") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
{ i am an mpz - write my members here }, { i am an mpz - write my members here }
{ i am an mpz - write my members here }, { i am an mpz - write my members here }
{ i am an mpz - write my members here }, { i am an mpz - write my members here }
{ i am an mpz - write my members here }
{ i am an mpz - write my members here }

{ i am an mpz - write my members here } * { i am an mpz - write my members here }
{ i am an mpz - write my members here } <--> { i am an mpz - write my members here }
```